# Cypress Error: could not find a registered alias. You have not aliased anything yet

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I have the following test:

```js
import { TEXTS_ALIAS } from "./constants";

describe(`Check page`, () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    let endpoint, fixture;
    switch (Cypress.currentTest.title) {
      case "INFOBOX":
        endpoint = "/api/q4/summary/";
        fixture = "q4/infobox.json";
        break;
      case "VIEW":
        endpoint = "/api/q4/resources/";
        fixture = "q4/resources.json";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    if (endpoint) {
      cy.intercept(endpoint, { fixture }).as("getData");
    }
    cy.interceptTexts();
  });

  it(`INFOBOX`, function () {
    cy.visit("/resources");
    cy.wait([TEXTS_ALIAS, "@getData"]);
    ...
  });

  it(`VIEW`, function () {
    cy.visit("/resources");
    cy.wait([TEXTS_ALIAS, "@getData"]);
    ...
  });
});
```

`interceptTexts` is a command in `commands.js`:

```js
import { TEXTS_ALIAS_NAME } from "../e2e/constants";

/**
 * @memberOf cy
 * @method interceptTexts
 * @returns undefined
 */
Cypress.Commands.add("interceptTexts", () => {
  cy.intercept("/api/texts/", { fixture: "texts.json" }).as(TEXTS_ALIAS_NAME);
});
```

The aliases are in `constants.js`:

```js
export const TEXTS_ALIAS_NAME = "getTexts";
export const TEXTS_ALIAS = "@getTexts";
```

It started to break on Cypress v12.15. I never had issues with aliases before v12.15.

I get the following error:

```
       INFOBOX:
     CypressError: `cy.wait()` could not find a registered alias for: `@getTexts`.
You have not aliased anything yet.
      at $Cy.aliasNotFoundFor (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:140235:74)
      at $Cy.getAlias (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:140178:12)
      at waitForXhr (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:151465:23)
      at <unknown> (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:151568:14)
      at tryCatcher (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:18744:23)
      at MappingPromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:15864:38)
      at PromiseArray._iterate (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:17066:31)
      at MappingPromiseArray.init (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:17030:10)
      at MappingPromiseArray._asyncInit (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:15833:10)
      at _drainQueueStep (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:13455:12)
      at _drainQueue (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:13444:9)
      at ../../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js.Async._drainQueues (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:13460:5)
      at Async.drainQueues (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:13330:14)
  From Your Spec Code:
      at Context.eval (webpack:///./cypress/e2e/q4-worldwide-resources.cy.js:69:7)
```

The strange thing is that I only get it on the first test `INFOBOX`. On the second test `VIEW` it never breaks.

I use `cy.interceptTexts();` at the end of `beforeEach()` and `cy.wait([TEXTS_ALIAS, "@getData"]);` at the start of tests in all of my test files and they all work. Only one breaks.

How can I fix it ?
Thank you.

Comment: If you switch the order of the tests (VIEW before INFOBOX) which test fails?

Comment: Then VIEW fails